Migrate thousands of test cases from TestNG framework to Cucumber(BDD)
I have requirement to migrate thousands of test cases from TestNG framework to cucumber. I tried searching and found a way to generate feature file and step definition files. Now looking for the ways how I can read the existing java code and relate to respective step definition. Any suggestions?
I have Test file like below.
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTest{

    @Test
    public void signInToPortal() {
        DriverUtility.openSignInPortalPage();
        DriverUtility.loginToFaceBook();
    }

    @Test
    public void loginToFaceBook() {
        DriverUtility.loginToFaceBook();
    }

}



Expectation:***
SampleTest.feature
Feature: Automatically generated from TestNG tests

  Scenario: open sign in portal page
    Given the user open sign in portal page
    When the user login to face book
    Then verification step yest to add

  Scenario: login to face book
    Given the user login to face book

StepDefinitions.java

package stepdefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @When("the user open sign in portal page")
    public void openSignInPortalPage() {
        DriverUtility.openSignInPortalPage();
    }


    @When("the user login to face book")
    public void loginToFaceBook() {
        DriverUtility.loginToFaceBook();
    }

}

I am able to generate feature file and step definitions but my stepdefinitions file is generated like below without java code
package stepdefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @When("the user open sign in portal page")
    public void openSignInPortalPage() {
        // TODO: implement this step
    }


    @When("the user login to face book")
    public void loginToFaceBook() {
        // TODO: implement this step
    }

}


Have a look at how to ask. If you want help with a specific step, then you need to show the code that doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Either that or you've not configured your glue path correctly. Have a look at the skeleton project, it has 3 steps, 1 defined, 2 undefined. Your project should follow a similar structure. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

I do not believe that you can just take 1000 arbitrary tests in TestNg and migrate them to Cucumber. Cucumber is more about test design pattern where steps are independent and where the flexibility is a tradeoff for readability. Your example looks simple, but I believe the real tests have more complicated flow control including cycles, complex data structures and complex asserts. Better show us some tests that well represent your typical case.
